# Typeswitch case attribute()?

Tags: css, xml, xquery, exist-db

I am trying to execute a typeswitch for all elements with a specific attribute, for instance `@test`, initially regardless of how the attribute is defined. This is what I have so far in the xql file:

```html
declare function tei2:tei2html($nodes as node()*) {
    for $node in $nodes
    return
        typeswitch ($node)  
          case attribute(test) return
                <b>{ tei2:tei2html($node/node()) }</b>
};
```

I have created a test attribute in an xml file `<p test="test">` but nothing happens--I was expecting that `<p>` to become bold. What am I missing? Is this possible, or would it be better to create a function to transform the attribute into a css class?

**UPDATED QUESTION**

I've added this typeswitch to tei2html.xql, and it sort of does what I want, but not quite.

Here is the new code:

```
case element(tei:div) return
            <p>
                {
                    if ($node/@type="subhead") then 
                        attribute class {$node/@type="subhead"} 
                    else 
                        ()
                    ,
                    tei2:tei2html($node/node())
                }
            </p>
```

The result is:

```
<p class="true">SECT. II.</p>
```

So, instead of adding the attribute "subhead," it's adding the attribute "true." What's going on here?

**UPDATED UPDATED QUESTION**

I'm a silly bird. I fixed it by changing the typeswitch line to:

```
attribute class {$node/@type="subhead"}
```

Done!

Comment: You most likely want to switch on an element and check it's attributes in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Let's work through what happens when you pass your `<p test="test">` element to the `tei2:tei2html()` function:

1. The function receives the `<p>` element as the `$nodes` parameter.
2. The FLWOR iterates through the `$nodes`, assigning `$node` to each. In the first iteration `$node` is your `<p>` element
3. The typeswitch expression looks at `$node` to see if it is an attribute. `<p>` is not an attribute, so it advances to the next test, or if there are no further tests, it returns the default (which you have not given here - in fact the code as presented would present an error because of a missing `default` expression).
4. If your `default` is `return ()`, the expression would end here, with 0 results.
5. If your `default` is `return tei:tei2html($node/node())` then the function would be called again on the child nodes of `<p test="test">` - namely, the `@test` attribute. This time, the attribute test would work, but it would return an empty `<b>` element, because, as Michael said, if `$node` is an attribute then `$node/node()` will select nothing because attributes do not have children.

More typically, in recursive typeswitch transformations, we handle attributes in the course of processing elements - as Adam suggested.

```
declare function tei2:tei2html($nodes as node()*) {
    for $node in $nodes
    return
        typeswitch ($node)  
            case element(p) return
                <p>
                    {
                        if ($node/@test) then 
                            attribute class {$node/@test} 
                        else 
                            ()
                        ,
                        tei2:tei2html($node/node())
                    }
                </p>
            default return tei2:tei2html($node/node())
};
```

This would transform `<p test="test">` into `<p class="test">`.

There's nothing illegal about an `attribute()` test, but in practice their processing is closely tied to their parent element, so most often recursive typeswitch transformations handle attributes in the course of processing their parent elements.

Comment: Joe, that is incredibly helpful--thank you for taking the time to explain so thoroughly! I will work through this and see where it takes me. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

If $node is an attribute, then it doesn't have any children, so `$node/node()` will select nothing.